# Deleting nginx sites-available and replacing it with a cloned sites-available

Tags: nginx

I have several conf files because i am hosting several domains to use same nginx installation. I have the confs prepared inside a git repo called sites-available. So when i delete nginx original sites-available, i want to clone my repo to fill the gap left.

However, when i look at the sites-available ownership

```
ubuntu@ip-0.0.0.0.0:~$ sudo ls -ld /etc/nginx/sites-available
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May  5 05:32 /etc/nginx/sites-available
```

its owned by root, which i am guessing is the nginx parent process.

Can i `sudo mkdir` or `sudo clone my_git_sites` available without worrying that the nginx parent process is going to be problematic somewhere down the line?.

Comment: The reason of the question is not clear. What is exactly the concern of sites-available being root?

Comment: Does the nginx process expect other files to be there such as hidden git files etc